# How can i get uploaded file path in php?

Tags: php

I have used this step `echo $_FILES["fileField"]["tmp_name"];` but result like this.

```
C:\xampp\tmp\phpA9EE.tmp
```

How can i get exact file path?

Comment: This is the tmp path, the exact path is something you do with move uploaded file.

Comment: using temp path can i access file content ? @lu.chmielewski

Comment: I guess it is just the same file moved to temporary location. I bet if you would change it's extension to the real file extension, it would open as it opens normally. But what you want to do is this: http://pl1.php.net/move_uploaded_file

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp - see the section "Saving the Uploaded File"

Comment: @lu.chmielewski i read that page. I need to upload a file(excel file) and get its content and insert the specific cell values to a db

Comment: Then again - you need to move it to some permanent location and read it from there. Additionally, you will have to add some xls php parsing class or function - but that's an additional comment.

Comment: @lu.chmielewski: don't link to W3fools. The site is crap and their php code samples range from downright bad to outright dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An uploaded file does not have a "full path", other than temporary location where PHP has stored it during the upload process.

For the security of users, the browser sends only a filename of where it came from on the remote computer; for *your* security, you should not blindly use this (security rule of thumb: anything sent by the user is suspect and could be used to attack your system). You might want to filter it through a whitelist (e.g. remove anything other than letters and numbers) and use it as a "friendly" upload name, or you might want to ignore it completely. The browser also sends a file type (e.g. `image/jpeg`); again, this *should not be trusted* - the only way to know the type of a file is to use a command that looks at the content and validates it.

As far as PHP is concerned, what has been uploaded is a chunk of binary data; it saves this to a randomly named file, which is the path you have echoed there. The PHP manual has [an introduction to how this works](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

With that path you can do one of two things:

- validate with `is_uploaded_file()`, and read the data with `file_get_contents()` or similar
- use `move_uploaded_file()` to put it in a permanent location of your choice